# Replace value in deep nested schema Spark Dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am new to pyspark. I am trying to understand how to access parquet file with multiple level of nested struct and array's. I need to replace some value in a data-frame (with nested schema) with null, I have seen this [solution](https://kb.databricks.com/data/update-nested-column.html) it works fine with structs but it not sure how this works with arrays.

My schema is something like this

```
|-- unitOfMeasure: struct
|    |-- raw: struct
|    |    |-- id: string
|    |    |-- codingSystemId: string
|    |    |-- display: string
|    |-- standard: struct
|    |    |-- id: string
|    |    |-- codingSystemId: string
|-- Id: string
|-- actions: array
|    |-- element: struct
|    |    |-- action: string
|    |    |-- actionDate: string
|    |    |-- actor: struct
|    |    |    |-- actorId: string
|    |    |    |-- aliases: array
|    |    |    |    |-- element: struct
|    |    |    |    |    |-- value: string
|    |    |    |    |    |-- type: string
|    |    |    |    |    |-- assigningAuthority: string
|    |    |    |-- fullName: string
```

What I wanted to do is replace `unitOfMeasure.raw.id` to null
and `actions.element.action` with null
and `actions.element.actor.aliases.element.value` with null keep the rest of my data frame untouched.

Is there any way that I can achieve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For array columns, it's a bit complicated compared to struct fields. 
One option is to explode the array into new column so that you could access and update the nested structs. After the update, you'll have to reconstruct the initial array column.

But I'd prefer using higher-order function [`transform`](https://docs.databricks.com/delta/data-transformation/higher-order-lambda-functions.html#apache-spark-24-built-in-functions-notebook) which is introduced for Spark >=2.4 Here is an example:

Input DF:

```
 |-- actions: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- action: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- actionDate: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- actor: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- actorId: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- aliases: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- assigningAuthority: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- type: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- value: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- fullName: string (nullable = true)

+--------------------------------------------------------------+
|actions                                                       |
+--------------------------------------------------------------+
|[[action_name1, 2019-12-08, [2, [[aa, t1, v1]], full_name1]]] |
|[[action_name2, 2019-12-09, [3, [[aaa, t2, v2]], full_name2]]]|
+--------------------------------------------------------------+
```

We pass a lambda function to `transfrom` which select all the struct fields and replace `actions.action` and `actions.actor.aliases.value` by `null`.

```
transform_expr = """transform (actions, x -> 
                               struct(null as action, 
                                      x.actionDate as actionDate, 
                                      struct(x.actor.actorId as actorId, 
                                             transform(x.actor.aliases, y -> 
                                                       struct(null as value, 
                                                              y.type as type, 
                                                              y.assigningAuthority as assigningAuthority)
                                                       ) as aliases,
                                            x.actor.fullName as fullName
                                      ) as actor
                                ))"""

df.withColumn("actions", expr(transform_expr)).show(truncate=False)
```

Output DF:

```
+------------------------------------------------+
|actions                                         |
+------------------------------------------------+
|[[, 2019-12-08, [2, [[, t1, aa]], full_name1]]] |
|[[, 2019-12-09, [3, [[, t2, aaa]], full_name2]]]|
+------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Do you know of any shortcuts when there are many, many nested variables? If fear, I will introduce an error at some place when I write hundreds of lines without syntax highlighting :/. I'm still on Spark 2.4.7, so `withField` is not available ...