# Spark: Replace Null value in a Nested column

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I would like to replace all the `n/a` values in the below dataframe to `unknown`.
It can be either `scalar` or `complex nested column`.
If it's a `StructField column` I can loop through the columns and replace `n\a` using `WithColumn`.
But I would like this to be done in a `generic way` inspite of the `type` of the column
as I dont want to specify the column names explicitly as there are 100's in my case?

```
case class Bar(x: Int, y: String, z: String)
case class Foo(id: Int, name: String, status: String, bar: Seq[Bar])

val df = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(
Seq(
  Foo(123, "Amy", "Active", Seq(Bar(1, "first", "n/a"))),
  Foo(234, "Rick", "n/a", Seq(Bar(2, "second", "fifth"),Bar(22, "second", "n/a"))),
  Foo(567, "Tom", "null", Seq(Bar(3, "second", "sixth")))
)).toDF

df.printSchema
df.show(20, false)
```

Result:

```
+---+----+------+---------------------------------------+
|id |name|status|bar                                    |
+---+----+------+---------------------------------------+
|123|Amy |Active|[[1, first, n/a]]                      |
|234|Rick|n/a   |[[2, second, fifth], [22, second, n/a]]|
|567|Tom |null  |[[3, second, sixth]]                   |
+---+----+------+---------------------------------------+
```

Expected Output:

```
+---+----+----------+---------------------------------------------------+
|id |name|status    |bar                                                |
+---+----+----------+---------------------------------------------------+
|123|Amy |Active    |[[1, first, unknown]]                              |
|234|Rick|unknown   |[[2, second, fifth], [22, second, unknown]]        |
|567|Tom |null      |[[3, second, sixth]]                               |
+---+----+----------+---------------------------------------------------+
```

Any suggestion on this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you like playing with RDDs, here's a simple, generic and evolutive solution :

```
  val naToUnknown = {r: Row =>
    def rec(r: Any): Any = {
      r match {
        case row: Row => Row.fromSeq(row.toSeq.map(rec))
        case seq: Seq[Any] => seq.map(rec)
        case s: String if s == "n/a" => "unknown"
        case _ => r
      }
    }
    Row.fromSeq(r.toSeq.map(rec))
  }

  val newDF = spark.createDataFrame(df.rdd.map{naToUnknown}, df.schema)
  newDF.show(false)
```

Output :

```
+---+----+-------+-------------------------------------------+
|id |name|status |bar                                        |
+---+----+-------+-------------------------------------------+
|123|Amy |Active |[[1, first, unknown]]                      |
|234|Rick|unknown|[[2, second, fifth], [22, second, unknown]]|
|567|Tom |null   |[[3, second, sixth]]                       |
+---+----+-------+-------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Great answer. I would only add that when doing `df.map`, you need to pass `RowEncoder(df.schema)` implicit param: `df.map{naToUnknown}(RowEncoder(df.schema))`

Answer (score 1):

It is somehow easy to replace nested values when you have only simple columns and structs. 
For array fields, you'll have to explode the structure before replacing or use UDF / higher-order functions, see my other answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59239011/1386551).

You can define a generic function that loops through DataFrame schema
and apply a lambda function `func` to replace what you want:

```
def replaceNestedValues(schema: StructType, func: Column => Column, path: Option[String] = None): Seq[Column] = {
  schema.fields.map(f => {
    val p = path.fold(s"`${f.name}`")(c => s"$c.`${f.name}`")
    f.dataType match {
      case s: StructType => struct(replaceNestedValues(s, func, Some(p)): _*).alias(f.name)
      case _ => func(col(p)).alias(f.name)
    }
  })
}
```

Before using this function, explode the array structure `bar` like this:

```
val df2 = df.select($"id", $"name", $"status", explode($"bar").alias("bar"))
```

Then, define a lambda function that takes a column and replace it with `unknown` when it is equal to `n/a` using `when/otherwise` functions, and apply transformation to columns using the above function:

```
val replaceNaFunc: Column => Column = c => when(c === lit("n/a"), lit("unknown")).otherwise(c)
val replacedCols = replaceNestedValues(df2.schema, replaceNaFunc)
```

Select new columns and groupBy to get back the `bar` array:

```
df2.select(replacedCols: _*).groupBy($"id", $"name", $"status").agg(collect_list($"bar").alias("bar")).show(false)
```

Gives:

```
+---+----+-------+-------------------------------------------+                  
|id |name|status |bar                                        |
+---+----+-------+-------------------------------------------+
|234|Rick|unknown|[[2, second, fifth], [22, second, unknown]]|
|123|Amy |Active |[[1, first, unknown]]                      |
|567|Tom |null   |[[3, second, sixth]]                       |
+---+----+-------+-------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Thanks @@blackbishop, here too I need to specify the column names explicitly.
Can this be modified without mentioning the column names as I have many scalar and nested fields?

Comment: @Leibnitz Unfortunately with this solution, you'll have to specify at least the array columns because we need to explode them before replacing values... For the other columns, one can get them from `df.columns` thought.

Answer (score 0):

You can define an UDF to deal with your Array and replace the items you want:

**UDF**

```
 val replaceNA =  udf((x:Row) => {
      val z = x.getString(2)
      if ( z == "n/a")
        Bar(x.getInt(0), x.getString(1), "unknow")
      else
        Bar(x.getInt(0), x.getString(1), x.getString(2))
      })
```

Once you have that UDF, you can **explode** your dataframe to hace each item in bar as a single row:

```
 val explodedDF = df.withColumn("exploded", explode($"bar"))
+---+----+------+--------------------+------------------+
| id|name|status|                 bar|          exploded|
+---+----+------+--------------------+------------------+
|123| Amy|Active|   [[1, first, n/a]]|   [1, first, n/a]|
|234|Rick|   n/a|[[2, second, fift...|[2, second, fifth]|
|234|Rick|   n/a|[[2, second, fift...| [22, second, n/a]|
|567| Tom|  null|[[3, second, sixth]]|[3, second, sixth]|
+---+----+------+--------------------+------------------+
```

Then **apply the previously defined UDF** to replace the items:

```
val replacedDF = explodedDF.withColumn("exploded", replaceNA($"exploded"))
+---+----+------+--------------------+--------------------+
| id|name|status|                 bar|            exploded|
+---+----+------+--------------------+--------------------+
|123| Amy|Active|   [[1, first, n/a]]|  [1, first, unknow]|
|234|Rick|   n/a|[[2, second, fift...|  [2, second, fifth]|
|234|Rick|   n/a|[[2, second, fift...|[22, second, unknow]|
|567| Tom|  null|[[3, second, sixth]]|  [3, second, sixth]|
+---+----+------+--------------------+--------------------+
```

And finally **grouping** all together with **collect_list** to return it to it's original state

```
 val resultDF = replacedDF.groupBy("id", "name", "status")
      .agg(collect_list("exploded").as("bar")).show(false)
+---+----+------+------------------------------------------+
|id |name|status|bar                                       |
+---+----+------+------------------------------------------+
|234|Rick|n/a   |[[2, second, fifth], [22, second, unknow]]|
|567|Tom |null  |[[3, second, sixth]]                      |
|123|Amy |Active|[[1, first, unknow]]                      |
+---+----+------+------------------------------------------+
```

**Putting al together in a single step:**

```
import org.apache.spark.sql._

 val replaceNA =  udf((x:Row) => {
          val z = x.getString(2)
          if ( z == "n/a")
            Bar(x.getInt(0), x.getString(1), "unknow")
          else
            Bar(x.getInt(0), x.getString(1), x.getString(2))
          }) 

df.withColumn("exploded", explode($"bar"))
 .withColumn("exploded", replaceNA($"exploded"))
 .groupBy("id", "name", "status")
 .agg(collect_list("exploded").as("bar"))
```

Comment: Thanks @@Scouto, still here I need to specify the column names explicitly.

Comment: You can groupBy but the schema except the array column