# How to change datatype of a field in a two-level schema tree?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Now I have a dataframe with schema:

```
root
 |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- st_one: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- tid: long (nullable = true)
 |    |-- st_two: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- score: long (nullable = true)
 |-- ts: double (nullable = true)
 |-- date: string (nullable = true)
```

I want to change **score**'s type from `long` to `double`. Is there any good solution?
BTW, I'm using `Scala`.

I've already known how to do it by "listing" all the fields. I want a more common method that could fit even st_two contains a thousand fields or more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can update the struct type column `st_one` like this:

```
val df1 = df.withColumn(
  "st_one",
  struct(
    $"st_one.tid",
    struct(
      $"st_one.st_two.name",
      $"st_one.st_two.score".cast("double").as("score")
    ).as("st_two")
  )
)
```

Comment: Thank you! But these codes are based on known fields or with fixed quantity. For example, if `st_two` contains a thousand fields, it's hard for me to list all fields and choose the one I want to update. Is there any more common method to solve it?@blackbishop

Comment: @Selyx It's a bit more complicated as you'll have to loop through all the schema fields. Please see my [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59544330/1386551) it can give you an idea on how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a complex cast:

```
val df2 = df.withColumn("st_one", $"st_one".cast("struct<tid:long, st_two:struct<name:string, score:double>>"))
```

Comment: Thank you! But these codes are based on known fields or with fixed quantity. For example, if st_two contains a thousand fields, it's hard for me to list all fields and choose the one I want to update. Is there any more common method to solve it? @mck