# suggestion for tune up the code which contains explode and groupby

Tags: scala, performance, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, explode

I wrote the code for below probelem but it has below problems. Please suggest me if some tuning can be done.

1. It takes more time I think.
2. there are 3 brands as of now. It is hardcoded. If more brands would be added, i need to add the code manually.

input dataframe schema :

```text
root
 |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- attrib: map (nullable = true)
 |    |-- key: string
 |    |-- value: string (valueContainsNull = true)
 |-- pref: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- pref_type: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- brand: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- tp_id: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- aff: float (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- pre_id: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- cr_date: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- up_date: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- pref_attrib: map (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- key: string
 |    |    |    |-- value: string (valueContainsNull = true)
```

expected output schema:

```text
root
 |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- attrib: map (nullable = true)
 |    |-- key: string
 |    |-- value: string (valueContainsNull = true)
 |-- pref: struct (nullable = false)
 |    |-- brandA: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = false)
 |    |    |    |-- pref_type: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- tp_id: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- aff: float (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- pref_id: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- cr_date: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- up_date: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- pref_attrib: map (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- key: string
 |    |    |    |    |-- value: string (valueContainsNull = true)
 |    |-- brandB: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = false)
 |    |    |    |-- pref_type: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- tp_id: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- aff: float (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- pref_id: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- cr_date: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- up_date: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- pref_attrib: map (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- key: string
 |    |    |    |    |-- value: string (valueContainsNull = true)
 |    |-- brandC: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = false)
 |    |    |    |-- pref_type: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- tp_id: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- aff: float (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- pref_id: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- cr_date: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- up_date: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- pref_attrib: map (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- key: string
 |    |    |    |    |-- value: string (valueContainsNull = true)
```

The processing can be done based on the brand attribute under preferences(`preferences.brand`)

I have written the below code for that:

```
def modifyBrands(inputDf: DataFrame): DataFrame ={
    val PreferenceProps = Array("pref_type", "tp_id", "aff", "pref_id", "cr_date", "up_date", "pref_attrib")
    import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
    val explodedDf = inputDf.select(col("id"), explode(col("pref")))
        .select(
            col("id"),
            col("col.pref_type"),
            col("col.brand"),
            col("col.tp_id"),
            col("col.aff"),
            col("col.pre_id"),
            col("col.cr_dt"),
            col("col.up_dt"),
            col("col.pref_attrib")
        ).cache()

    val brandAddedDf = explodedDf
        .withColumn("brandA", when(col("brand") === "brandA", struct(PreferenceProps.head, PreferenceProps.tail:_*)).as("brandA"))
        .withColumn("brandB", when(col("brand") === "brandB", struct(PreferenceProps.head, PreferenceProps.tail:_*)).as("brandB"))
        .withColumn("brandC", when(col("brand") === "brandC", struct(PreferenceProps.head, PreferenceProps.tail:_*)).as("brandC"))
        .cache()

    explodedDf.unpersist()

    val groupedDf = brandAddedDf.groupBy("id").agg(
        collect_list("brandA").alias("brandA"),
        collect_list("brandB").alias("brandB"),
        collect_list("brandC").alias("brandC")
    ).withColumn("preferences", struct(
        when(size(col("brandA")).notEqual(0), col("brandA")).alias("brandA"),
        when(size(col("brandB")).notEqual(0), col("brandB")).alias("brandB"),
        when(size(col("brandC")).notEqual(0), col("brandC")).alias("brandC"),
    )).drop("brandA", "brandB", "brandC")
      .cache()
    brandAddedDf.unpersist()

    val idAttributesDf = inputDf.select("id", "attrib").cache()

    val joinedDf = idAttributesDf.join(groupedDf, "id")
    groupedDf.unpersist()
    idAttributesDf.unpersist()
    joinedDf.printSchema()
    joinedDf // returning joined df which will be wrote as paquet file.
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simplify your code using higher-order function [`filter`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/#filter) on arrays. Just map through brand names and for-each one return a filtered array from `pref`. This way you avoid the exploding / grouping part.

Here's a complete example:

```scala
val data = """{"id":1,"attrib":{"key":"k","value":"v"},"pref":[{"pref_type":"type1","brand":"brandA","tp_id":"id1","aff":"aff1","pre_id":"pre_id1","cr_date":"2021-01-06","up_date":"2021-01-06","pref_attrib":{"key":"k","value":"v"}},{"pref_type":"type1","brand":"brandB","tp_id":"id1","aff":"aff1","pre_id":"pre_id1","cr_date":"2021-01-06","up_date":"2021-01-06","pref_attrib":{"key":"k","value":"v"}},{"pref_type":"type1","brand":"brandC","tp_id":"id1","aff":"aff1","pre_id":"pre_id1","cr_date":"2021-01-06","up_date":"2021-01-06","pref_attrib":{"key":"k","value":"v"}}]}"""
val inputDf = spark.read.json(Seq(data).toDS)

val brands = Seq("brandA", "brandB", "brandC")

// or getting them from input dataframe
// val brands = inputDf.select("pref.brand").as[Seq[String]].collect.flatten


val brandAddedDf = inputDf.withColumn(
  "pref",
  struct(brands.map(b => expr(s"filter(pref, x -> x.brand = '$b')").as(b)): _*)
)

brandAddedDf.printSchema
//root
// |-- attrib: struct (nullable = true)
// |    |-- key: string (nullable = true)
// |    |-- value: string (nullable = true)
// |-- id: long (nullable = true)
// |-- pref: struct (nullable = false)
// |    |-- brandA: array (nullable = true)
// |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
// |    |    |    |-- aff: string (nullable = true)
// |    |    |    |-- brand: string (nullable = true)
// |    |    |    |-- cr_date: string (nullable = true)
// |    |    |    |-- pre_id: string (nullable = true)
// |    |    |    |-- pref_attrib: struct (nullable = true)
// |    |    |    |    |-- key: string (nullable = true)
// |    |    |    |    |-- value: string (nullable = true)
// |    |    |    |-- pref_type: string (nullable = true)
// |    |    |    |-- tp_id: string (nullable = true)
// |    |    |    |-- up_date: string (nullable = true)
// |    |-- brandB: array (nullable = true)
// |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
// |    |    |    |-- aff: string (nullable = true)
// |    |    |    |-- brand: string (nullable = true)
// |    |    |    |-- cr_date: string (nullable = true)
// |    |    |    |-- pre_id: string (nullable = true)
// |    |    |    |-- pref_attrib: struct (nullable = true)
// |    |    |    |    |-- key: string (nullable = true)
// |    |    |    |    |-- value: string (nullable = true)
// |    |    |    |-- pref_type: string (nullable = true)
// |    |    |    |-- tp_id: string (nullable = true)
// |    |    |    |-- up_date: string (nullable = true)
// |    |-- brandC: array (nullable = true)
// |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
// |    |    |    |-- aff: string (nullable = true)
// |    |    |    |-- brand: string (nullable = true)
// |    |    |    |-- cr_date: string (nullable = true)
// |    |    |    |-- pre_id: string (nullable = true)
// |    |    |    |-- pref_attrib: struct (nullable = true)
// |    |    |    |    |-- key: string (nullable = true)
// |    |    |    |    |-- value: string (nullable = true)
// |    |    |    |-- pref_type: string (nullable = true)
// |    |    |    |-- tp_id: string (nullable = true)
// |    |    |    |-- up_date: string (nullable = true)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the short and sweet version of the code. One more problem is still there. line // val brands = inputDf.select("pref.brand").as[Seq[String]].collect.flatten is giving the error regarding encoders. that is doesn't find encoder for that

Comment: @NickyPatel try adding `import spark.implicits._`?

Comment: in this line of code
inputDf.withColumn("pref",
  struct(brands.map(b => expr(s"filter(pref, x -> x.brand = '$b')").as(b)): _*)
how can i ommit some of the column not required. i.e. brand is coming as a parent and i am not looking for the brand again inside as a child. Or if I need to remove some attribute from all the attributes of pref.

Comment: @NickyPatel then you can use `transform` function over the filtered array: e.g. if you want to only keep fields `aff`, `cr_date` and `tp_id` so the code would be: `transform(filter(...), y -> named_struct(y.aff, y.cr_date, y.tp_id))`. you see my [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59239011/1386551) on how to use transform to update

Comment: Thank you so much for the time you spend and providing the required solution. :)

Answer (score 1):

I think they're are a couple issues with how you are doing your code, but the real way to tell where you have a problem with your code is to look at the SPARK UI.  I find the "Jobs" tab and the "SQL" tab very informative to figure out where the code is spending most of its time.  Then see if those parts can be re-written to give you more speed.  Some of the items I point out below may not matter if there is a bottleneck elsewhere that really is where most of the time is being spent.

There are reasons to create nested structures (Like you are for Brand). I'm just not sure I see the payoff here and it's not explained.  It should be considered why you are maintaining this structure and what the benefit is. Is there a performance gain for maintaining it?  Or is it simply an artifact of how the data was created?

General tips that might help a little:

In general you should only cache code that you will use more than once.  You have a lot of code you don't use more than once but you still cache.

Small, small performance boost. (So in other words when you need every millisecond...)  withColumn actually doesn't perform as well as select.  (Likely due to some object creation) where possible use select instead of withColumn.  Not really worth re-writing your code unless you really need every milli-second.

Comment: Thanks for spending time and writing very valuable expert advice here but while going through the code, i found that explode and groupby was taking the most of execution time.