# Add new element to nested array of structs pyspark

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe with the following schema using **pyspark**:

```text
|-- suborders: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- trackingStatusHistory: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- trackingStatusUpdatedAt: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- trackingStatus: string (nullable = true)
```

What I want to do is create a new `deliveredat` element for each `suborders` array using conditions.

I need to find the date within the `trackingStatusHistory` array where `trackingStatusHistory.trackingStatus = 'delivered'`. If this `trackingStatus` exists, the new `deliveredat` element will receive the date in `trackingStatusHistory.trackingStatusUpdatedAt`. If doesn't exist, receive `null`.

How can I do this using pyspark?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that using higher-order functions [`transform`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/#transform) + [`filter`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/#filter) on arrays. For each struct element of `suborders` array you add a new field by  filtering the sub-array `trackingStatusHistory` and getting the delivery date, like this:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df = df.withColumn(
    "suborders",
    F.expr("""transform(
                suborders, 
                x -> struct(
                        filter(x.trackingStatusHistory, y -> y.trackingStatus = 'delivered')[0].trackingStatusUpdatedAt as deliveredAt,
                        x.trackingStatusHistory as trackingStatusHistory
                        )
                )
    """)
)
```

Comment: Can you help me understand why do you need to use this "expr" function and the triple quotes? I tried to look it up on the internet, but I didn't find anything like it. Also, here in the question I omitted several fields inside suborders and they all disappeared with the transform. Is there an easy solution to keep all fields?

Comment: @Christian triple quotes is called "multi-line string". It s used to write string in multiple lines as above. `expr` is used because before spark 3.1, functions likes `transform` and `filter` where not available with DataFrame API. But if you have spark 3.1+, you can use [`transform`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.transform.html) and [filter](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.filter.html) with python lambda functions.

Comment: @Christian for your second question. to keep the fields you need to recreate the whole inner struct and specify each field to keep. You can see my other posts: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59239011/1386551) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70635268/1386551)