# How to modify pyspark dataframe nested struct column

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, struct, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to anonymize/hash a nested column, but haven't been successful. The schema looks something like this:

```text
-- abc: struct (nullable = true)
|    |-- xyz: struct (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- abc123: string (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- services: struct (nullable = true)
|    |    |    |-- service: array (nullable = true)
|    |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
|    |    |    |    |    |-- type: string (nullable = true)
|    |    |    |    |    |-- subtype: string (nullable = true)
```

I need to change (anonymize/hash) value of `type` column.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For Spark 3.1+, there is a column method [`withField`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.Column.withField.html) that can be used to update struct fields.

Assuming this is your input dataframe (corresponding to the schema you provided):

```
from pyspark.sql import Row

df = spark.createDataFrame([
    Row(abc=Row(xyz=Row(abc123="value123", services=[Row(type="type1", subtype="subtype1")])))
])

df.show(truncate=False)
#+---------------------------------+
#|abc                              |
#+---------------------------------+
#|{{value123, [{type1, subtype1}]}}|
#+---------------------------------+
```

You can achieve that using [`transform`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/#transform) on the array `services` to hash the field `type` for each struct element (here I used [`xxhash64`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/#xxhash64) function to illustrate) like this:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df2 = df.withColumn(
    "abc",
    F.col("abc").withField(
        "xyz",
        F.col("abc.xyz").withField(
            "services",
            F.expr("transform(abc.xyz.services, x -> struct(xxhash64(x.type) as type, x.subtype))")
        )
    )
)

df2.show(truncate=False)
#+-----------------------------------------------+
#|abc                                            |
#+-----------------------------------------------+
#|{{value123, [{2134479862461603894, subtype1}]}}|
#+-----------------------------------------------+
```

---

For older Spark versions, you'll need to recreate the whole structs in order to update the fields, which makes it tedious when there are many nested fields. In your case it would be like this:

```
df2 = df.withColumn(
    "abc",
    F.struct(
        F.struct(
            F.col("abc.xyz.abc123"),
            F.expr(
                "transform(abc.xyz.services, x -> struct(xxhash64(x.type) as type, x.subtype))"
            ).alias("services")
        ).alias("xyz")
    )
)
```