# Replacing column values in nested structure spark dataframe

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I got VCF data format in Databricks. I wish to rename the subjects based on dictionary.

I got dictionary where I got the key-new names. Then I got function to get the new values and return values work so far:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

keys= {'old_name': 'new_name'}
mapping_func = lambda x: keys.get(x) 
df.withColumn('foo', udf(mapping_func, F.StringType())('geno.sampleId'))
```

Producing new column `foo`. What I need to assign the values in the nested structure: (Last row)

```scala
StructField(contigName,StringType,true)
StructField(start,LongType,true)
StructField(end,LongType,true)
StructField(names,ArrayType(StringType,true),true)
StructField(referenceAllele,StringType,true)
StructField(alternateAlleles,ArrayType(StringType,true),true)
StructField(qual,DoubleType,true)
StructField(filters,ArrayType(StringType,true),true)
StructField(splitFromMultiAllelic,BooleanType,true)
StructField(geno,StructType(List(StructField(sampleId,StringType,true),StructField(CN,IntegerType,true),StructField(phased,BooleanType,true),StructField(calls,ArrayType(IntegerType,true),true))),true)
```

Something like this:

```
 df =  df.withColumn(F.col('geno').sampleId, udf(mapping_func, F.StringType())('geno.sampleId'))
```

But this says

> Column is not iterable

How would I go about assigning the values to proper place?

Scala 2.12 and spark 3.01

Comment: F.col() returns a Column: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.Column.html#pyspark.sql.Column. Try F.col('geno.sampleId')

Comment: @EmilianoMartinez Thank you for suggestion. It still says 'column is not iterable.

Comment: Take a look to some examples: https://sparkbyexamples.com/pyspark/pyspark-udf-user-defined-function/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my understanding, you don't need to use UDF here. You can simply use a map column expression instead:

```py
from itertools import chain
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

keys_map = F.create_map(*[F.lit(x)for x in chain(*keys.items())])
```

Now, to update a nested field in a struct you need to recreate the whole struct column (for Spark 3.1+, you'd use [`withField` method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70623347/how-to-modify-pyspark-dataframe-nested-struct-column)):

```py
df = df.withColumn(
    "geno",
    F.struct(
        keys_map[F.col("geno.sampleId")].alias("sampleId"), # replaces sampleId value according to your keys mapping
        F.col("geno.CN").alias("CN"),
        F.col("geno.phased").alias("phased"),
        F.col("geno.calls").alias("calls")
    )
)
```

Comment: Thank you. I managed to figure it out yesterday and it's quite similar to this.